# Removing undefined values in angularjs dropdown

Tags: php, html, angularjs, ng-options

I am using angularjs(ng-options) to create a select dropdown that is populated using a sql query in php to return my list of options as json.

This works great for 1 dropdown..I am now trying to add a second dropdown that uses a different query.  I use php array_merge to merge the 2 query result arrays, then json_encode the merged array.

Both dropdowns populate, but both have a lot of unwanted undefined values and I am not sure why..The undefined values do not exist when I only return 1 singular array (rather than merging the two)

I don't have any undefined result objects in the json itself. Only in the select dropdown

```js
 getInfo();
function getInfo(){
// Sending request to EmpDetails.php files 
$http.post('databaseFiles/options.php').success(function(result){
// Stored the returned data into scope 
$scope.options = result;
console.log(result);
});
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDepartment" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.department for option in options ">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Before attribute value to ```$scope.options```, check if ```typeof result.data === 'undefined'```

Comment: The code snippet you posted will not run, because of this error "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined"  can you post the contents of $scope.options?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing my issue by adding a filter to my ng-options to remove undefined values

```html
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDepartment" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.department for option in options  **| filter : { id : '!!' }** " >
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
</select>
```